# How to find and replace this string in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a string variable that looks like this `x\y\z`

The length of `x, y and z` may vary, but they all have two slashes `\`

How can I replace the part before the second `\`, including itself, with some other value?

I tried this but it didn't work:

`replace newvar=ustrregexra(oldvar, "\", "", 2)`

It gave me a blank `newvar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A personal law for string manipulations is that regular expressions are great, but there's often a simpler and more direct way to solve the problem.

On what you have told us, the problem reduces to

1. Finding the position of the last (second) backslash `\`.
2. Replacing characters up to and including that by something else.

Here is one way to do it:

```
clear 
set obs 2 
gen foo = cond(_n == 1, "frog\toad\newt", "dragon\griffin\unicorn")
gen bar = "whatever" + substr(foo, strrpos(foo, "\") + 1, .) 
list 

     +------------------------------------------+
     |                    foo               bar |
     |------------------------------------------|
  1. |         frog\toad\newt      whatevernewt |
  2. | dragon\griffin\unicorn   whateverunicorn |
     +------------------------------------------+
```

The solution doesn't hinge on the replacement text being a fixed string, as a string expression could be used instead.

A regular expression solution for this problem would have to start with the recognition that backslashes in regular expressions have their own role.

It's not obvious from your question that you need functions that handle Unicode.

See also `split`. You could `split` on backslashes and then use the last variable so produced.